# React Apollo client perform multiple mutations that depend on each other

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Consider the scenario where the **useMutation()** hook is used:

1. Mutation 1 response includes **`id1`**
2. Mutation 2 uses **`id1`** as an input variable along with some other variables.
3. Mutation 2 responds with **`id2`**.
4. Mutation 3 uses **`id2`** as an input variable.

How do I handle the asynchronous responses?
With REST API we could do something like:

```
try{
  let data1 = await mutation1(...)
  let data2 = await mutation2(data1.id1, ...)  
  let data3 = await mutation2(data2.id2, ...)
}catch(err) => {
  console.error(err)
}
```

How do I do this with GraphQL, Apollo Client?

Answer (score 1):

With React Saga you could do that like this:

1. create your mutation function

   ```
   export const mutateMethods = async (object: any) => {
      return await apolloClient.mutate({
        mutation: gql`
          ${object}
        `,
      });
    };
   ```
2. Create your reducer and action
3. Create your sagaIterator function

> ```
> export function* actionSaga(action: any): SagaIterator {
>   try {
>     const res_0 = yield call(mutateMethods, action.payload);
>     const res_1 = yield call(mutateMethods, res_0);
>     const res_2 = yield call(mutateMethods, res_1);
>     yield put(reducer_action_success());
>   } catch (error) {
>     yield put(reducer_action_failed());
>   }
> }
> ```

4. Dispatch the action that will call your sagaAction

> ```
> dispatch({type:"CALL_MY_MUTATIONS", payload:data})
> ```